# how to make a post call to nodejs server?

Tags: android, node.js

Just insted of using PHP as a serverside laguage i want to use Nodejs. 
I have created Rest API using node js .

how to make a post call to nodejs server?

Comment: That's not true, you can accept any type of parameters in NodeJS. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

connection with android app usually involves rest api. of course `nodeJs` supports Rest api. Look for guides on how to implement Rest Api using nodeJs. quick one that i found is: http://pixelhandler.com/posts/develop-a-restful-api-using-nodejs-with-express-and-mongoose